# While Not Equal to String

Tags: java

I'm making a text based RPG game and I am creating a chooseClass method. See the code:

```
public static void classChoice(){
    String cont =null;
    String[] classes = {"rogue", "wizard", "knight", "archer"};
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    do{
        System.out.println("Choose your class (Rogue, Wizard, Knight, Archer): ");
        cont = input.next();
        if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("rogue")){
            System.out.println("You have chosen the Rogue!");
        } else if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("wizard")) {
            System.out.println("You have chosen the Wizard!");
        } else if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("knight")) {
            System.out.println("You have chosen the Knight!");
        } else if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("archer")) {
            System.out.println("You have chosen the Archer!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Choose a valid class!");
        } 
    } while(!cont.equals(classes));
}
```

So I made a string array for all of the classes, and I thought that I could make the user input "cont" and say that while it is not equal to any of the "classes" array values, then print the message "Choose a valid class!".  It isn't working, any ideas?

Answer (score 10):

`cont.equals(classes)` doesn't test whether `cont` is in `classes`. It tests whether `cont` is equal to `classes`. Since `cont` is a String and `classes` is an array of Strings, this will never be true.

I recommend using `Arrays.asList` to make a list of classes. Then, you can test whether the list contains `cont`:

```
classes = Arrays.asList("rogue", "wizard", "knight", "archer");

... while (!classes.contains(cont));
```

Comment: In addition, a foreach loop would clean up the numerous if-elseifs nicely.

Comment: @Vulcan: Indeed it would. It's rather silly to define `classes` and then only use it for the do-while test.

Comment: Did your while statement and got the error "Syntax error, insert "while ( Expression ) ;" to complete DoStatement"

Comment: @AdamBasham: You probably screwed up your braces.

Comment: do cont=input.next(); while (!classes.contains(cont)); System.out.println("You have chosen the "+cont);

Answer (score 4):

You should use an enum for this purpose. it would have a method to return an enum for an input string, and then you could find out what the value was.

Comment: I think that this is the best answer.  It would simplify the code, and make easy-to-pass-around values.

Comment: Agree.  Any time you have a list of constants known at compile time, you should automatically think about expressing them as an `enum`.  You can even extend Java enums so that each enum object can contain all the metadata for each character class, as well as methods that operate on it.  Enums are really the way to go in cases like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can't compare a single String to an array of Strings. The correct way to think of this logic is, "does the set of valid classes contain whatever the user typed in?". A small snippet of what that might look like is as follows:

```
Set<String> classes = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("Rogue", "Wizard")); // ...etc.
while (!classes.contains(cont));
```

Answer (score 2):

`cont` is a `String` and `classes` is a `String[]` (String array), so they will never be equal.  What you want to know is if `classes` contains `cont`.  I would suggest changing classes to a `List<String>` so you can use the `contains` method.

```
final List<String> CLASSES = Arrays.asList("rogue", "wizard", "knight", "archer");
```

And then

```
while(!CLASSES.contains(cont));
```

That said, your variable names and general design could use some work.  For starters `cont` should probably be named something more descriptive like `userClassChoice`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you actually *need* the array, but let's assume you do:

```
String[] classes = {"rogue", "wizard", "knight", "archer"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(classes);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
do (
    System.out.println("Choose your class (Rogue, Wizard, Knight, Archer): ");
    cont = input.next();
} while (!list.contains(cont.toLowerCase()))
```

You can refine it, but this is the basics of something that will work.

Answer (score 1):

this will check if cont value is in your array :

```
 while (!classes.asList("rogue", "wizard", "knight", "archer").contains(cont))
```

You try to compare a string cont with an array classes.

Answer (score 1):

The statement in while block is incorrect. You shouldn't compare con with classes array

Answer (score 1):

Among other things, you have a syntax error:

```
if (cont.equalsIgnoreCase("rogue")){
    System.out.println("You have chosen the Rogue!");
}   // <<< -- syntax error
}else if(cont.equalsIgnoreCase("wizard")){
```

---

If you indented your code *properly* that error would be much easier to see.